# jquery fancybox pop customize?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

i am using fancybox function in jquery. i am opening loign box on click a tag and calling login box html in its href attribute, i spepartly have login box html within it i have another link name "register" on this i calling another fancybox and i want to refresh page on its close. but this is not happning. here is code below

```
$(".login").fancybox({
        'padding': 0,
        'margin': 0,
        'width': '45',
        'height': '480.0',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe'


    });


 $(".register").fancybox({
        'padding': 0,
        'margin': 0,
        'width': '45',
        'height': '480.0',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'onClosed' : function () { self.parent.location.reload(); }

    });

<a href="login.html" class="login">login</a>

//inside login.html (it is showing on when popup comes)

<a href="register.html" class="register">register</a> // register class not applying of this, it is coming under login class
```

Comment: can any one solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using an iframe to load the data in the fancy box you dont need to reference to the parent, try with:

```
'onClosed' : function () { window.location.reload(); }
```

Comment: actully $(".register").fancybox not appying on <a href="register.html" class="register">register</a> this link. register.html coming under login pop class

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. Do you mean that when clicking on the register link you get the fancybox with the login.html content?

Comment: first when we click login link the we get the fancybox with login.html within it when we click register link we get the fancybox again with register.html content. i want to refresh register.html content on refresh